# Photo Grid Column Layout

Tags: html, css, image, grid

I want to make a grid using divs and I want to make sure they all have the same width but different heights. I do want them to wrap, but not on a new line, but under the first available spot of space. If you need any explanation, let me know!

This is pretty much the idea: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFxDz.jpg

Or also this:

[image: column photo grid layout]]

I just need a simple explanation though! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## Pure CSS Solution (Masonry Layout Without Javascript)

It's now also possible to do this without javascript using [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) (take a look at [this tutorial](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/))

```css
.masonry {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 5px;
}
img {
  break-inside: avoid;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/200/abstract" alt>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/100/250/abstract" alt>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/130/abstract" alt>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/100/240/abstract" alt>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/220/abstract" alt>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/180/abstract" alt>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/210/abstract" alt>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/100/170/abstract" alt>
</div>
```

## Using Javascript

An older solution that you will find has been pretty popular is to use the [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html#imagesloaded) library - see [this example](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/RPKgEN).

All the code that it requires is:

```
// init Masonry
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
  // options...
});
// layout Masonry after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.masonry('layout');
});
```

Comment: Thankyou, I am going to dive into that!  @jcuenod

Comment: I was playing around with the flexbox and I indeed found a way, I just didn't like how I did it. I made three rows, with all the divs or images same width but different hieght, and a display: block but I saw this video on youtube, and I just couldn't figure out how to do it without the flexbox. I'm learning new things everyday!

Answer (score 0):

[Isotope javascript plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html) has the layout mode that does exactly what you want. You can preview the layouts with examples. If you don't have any javascript skills you can use data attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The way I make something like this is first take a closer look to your image and you will notice 3 columns.

This 3 columns are containers of 3 different divs in **float** and **width: 33.33%** or an **inline-block** that generates the same result.

Inside this columns are your items that was **height: auto** though divs always work like this anyway.

The fancy white space is done by this chunk of code

```
// update the value in your convenience
border: 4px solid transparent;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

instead of using margin or padding we use border. This border will act as a independent padding that does not expand the background color you have in the div, at the same time does not create margins outside the item that pushes it out of the design. This will preserve the **33.33% width** look.

Hope that helps

Comment: This is exactly what I did, i just wanted something different.

Comment: If you want the other one it can be done using **position: absolute;** and you need to do it using JavaScript. You  need to record each and every positioning of an item based on heights and widths. I can't provide an example as I am using mobile but its how it works.